# How to display data label on top of nvd3 multi bar chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, d3.js, nvd3.js

I tried a few different methods I found online. For example, the one below and "showValues". However, none of these actually work. Can someone provide an example of how to do this properly?

```
d3.selectAll('.nv-multibar .nv-group').each(function(group){
  var g = d3.select(this);

  // Remove previous labels if there is any
  g.selectAll('text').remove();
  g.selectAll('.nv-bar').each(function(bar){
    var b = d3.select(this);
    var barWidth = b.attr('width');
    var barHeight = b.attr('height');

    g.append('text')
      // Transforms shift the origin point then the x and y of the bar
      // is altered by this transform. In order to align the labels
      // we need to apply this transform to those.
      .attr('transform', b.attr('transform'))
      .text(function(){
        // Two decimals format
        return parseFloat(bar.y).toFixed(2);
      })
      .attr('y', function(){
        // Center label vertically
        var height = this.getBBox().height;
        return parseFloat(b.attr('y')) - 10; // 10 is the label's magin from the bar
      })
      .attr('x', function(){
        // Center label horizontally
        var width = this.getBBox().width;
        return parseFloat(b.attr('x')) + (parseFloat(barWidth) / 2) - (width / 2);
      })
         .attr('class', 'bar-values');
      });
    });
```

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle/plunkr? That method should work.

Comment: @jeznag where did you add this set of code? is it within the nv.addGraph(function() {} section or the $(document).ready(function(){} section? And did you change anything within this code?

Comment: I didn't do anything. You need to set up a JSFiddle/Plunkr otherwise it's impossible for anyone to help you because you haven't provided data.